# How to divide a group of items into three columns using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of items that need to show in maximum of 3 columns. The issue is when I try to print them using a for loop it put them all in one column. How to put them in a separate column once they reach to a certain number.

Lets say, I have 99 items, 99/3 would be 33 so I would need to have 33 items per column. I tried to change the height of column which is 1px but could not solve it.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <c:forEach var="items" items="${Items}">
        ${item}
        <br />
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

**Current Output**

```
item1
...
item99
```

**Desired Output**

```
 item1     item34    item67
   ...       ...       ...
   item33    item67    item99
```

Comment: Whats that negative vote for? I am not that intelligent to take a guess :D

Comment: Please leave a comment if you're going to downvote.

Comment: Suggestion @Jack, it would help to edit your question so you mention that you want answers to achieve the columns through JSP templating.

Comment: what current output you are getting?

Comment: @JamesM.Lay I would like to solve the issye no matter which way. However, I prefer to solve it with bootstrap.

Comment: While I don't know JSP so can't help with an example answer, have at look at the modulus operator (%) which gives you the remainder of a divisor. You can use that to know when to create a new column.

Comment: @Steve I can use modulus but not sure how to add a new column. would you help me with a psudocode for any part that you do not know how to do.

Comment: @Jack psudo codey answer posted, may not be 100% correct but should give you the idea.

Comment: you seems to be passing the same variable as collection and one of the collection. use `var= "item"` instead of `var = "items"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating in between the div with col-md-3 so it is in one column.
Try this

```
<c:forEach var="items" items="${Items}" varStatus="status">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ${item}
    </div>
    <c:if test="${(status.index) % 3 == 0}">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: This is on the right track, but it doesn't solve the problem of how to break to a new row once you've iterated 3 times.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay thats correct, bootstrap has 12 columns per row;therefore it automatically goes to the next row.

Comment: Because bootstrap col-*-* clasees use float left style so the elements are floating to another layers in the page so we use clearfix.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code answer, full disclosure this is off the top of my head and hasn't been tested, but it hopefully gives you the idea.

```
var itemsPerColumn = totalItems / numberOfColumns (ie. 99/3 = 33)
var currentItem = 0;

<div class="col-md-3">
foreach item
    if currentItem % itemsPerColumn = 0 // current item divides into items per column with no remainder, so it's 33, 66, 99 etc
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
    end if
    ${item}
end foreach
</div>
```